# In Jenkinsfile get git files in current branch into a list (windows)

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, groovy

I am using a declarative pipeline, and want to get a list of files added/removed/modified in the working branch.  I would like to get that into a groovy list variable for subsequent conditionals.

Environment- currently using git on a windows slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-Access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job.

```
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
   for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
    def entry = entries[j]
    echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
    def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
    for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
        def file = files[k]
        echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how we get full path as file.path of changed file is giving just file name, not the location